# MySQL join while counting on joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

When you have a table which has relationships with 2 others through FKs, is it possible to query the main table while only counting how many times its ID exists in the other 2?

For example:

```
    id  title    product_id  contact_id
------  -------  ----------  ----------
    11  Mug             110          33
    11  Mug             110         297
    11  Mug             378          33
    11  Mug             378         297
    12  Monster         299          75
    12  Monster         299         291
    12  Monster         299         296
```

My query which results in above:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.title, t2.product_id, t3.contact_id FROM t1
    JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.rfq_id
    JOIN t3 ON t1.id = t3.rfq_id
```

I'm only interested in the `COUNT()`:

```
    id  title    product_count  contact_count
------  -------  -------------  -------------
    11  Mug                  2              2
    12  Monster              1              3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `group by` and `count` only `distinct` values:

```
select t1.id
     , t1.title
     , count(distinct t2.product_id) as product_count 
     , count(distinct t3.contact_id) as contact_count
from t1
join t2 on t1.id = t2.rfq_id
join t3 on t1.id = t3.rfq_id
group by t1.id
       , t1.title
```

Comment: @enchance: Because all columns listed in the `select`  should be either aggregated (with `count`, for example) or present in the `group by` clause to explicitly set what you want your output to be. MySQL is too liberal with this, so you won't get any errors, but it can result in something you have not expected.

Comment: Just curious, if I have more fields like `t1.created_at`, etc. must I also append it to the list of `GROUP BY` or are `id` and `title` enough?

Comment: @enchance: Well, it depends on the output, maybe you should join table to itself, and retrieve `t1.created_at` according to it's unique  `t1.id`.

Comment: @enchance - that's potentially only a problem because it looks like you haven't completely normalized your table.  If you moved `title` off to another table, it wouldn't be in the `GROUP BY` (however, you'd probably want to do the grouping in a subquery).  Another question: are `product` and `contact` related to each other, or only to `t1`?  Also, the query here ignores _both_ if either is missing.  If there's no `product_id = 110`, only one contact gets counted, even if both are present.

Comment: No, `product` and `contact` are not related. They're only tied to `t1` in this sample. Don't subqueries use more resources? Can you give an example on what it would look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try these

```
  SELECT t1.id, t1.title, 
         count(distinct t2.product_id) as product_id, 
         count(distinct  t3.contact_id) as contact_id FROM t1
  JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.rfq_id
  JOIN t3 ON t1.id = t3.rfq_id
  group by t1.id, t1.title
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.title, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT t2.product_id) AS product_count, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT t3.contact_id) AS contract_count 
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.rfq_id
JOIN t3 ON t1.id = t3.rfq_id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.title
```

Comment: Why is `t1.title` needed? Sorry, I have a hard time understanding `GROUP BY` using 2 or more fields.

Comment: @enchance It is a SQL requirement that every non-aggregated column of the `SELECT` clause must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. MySQL is more relaxed in this issue, so you can leave `t1.title` out of the `GROUP BY` if you like. I wouldn't recommend this though.